# Uploading Images from GitHub to WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, web, github

I am new to website development and I'm using WordPress to create a website to upload real-time forecast results.

The results are collected from an onsite device in a specific location that the model should be run on and is being uploaded to GitHub every 4 hours. The previous data will be replaced by the next one each time a new image is available.

The question is I'm trying to upload those results (.png images) to my website but WordPress does not show the image on the website. It just shows the link.

Do you have any idea how I fix uploading images from GitHub repository to my website.Is there any other way that I could transfer the forecast results to my website (I do have the option to upload the results somewhere else)?

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to do it? If you go into the page text editor (not the visual editor) and paste this

```
    <img src="*The-link-to-your-image-here*.png"/>
```

It should work just fine.

I could then help you with formatting the images, or you can look into using classes for css to style the images with a resource such as https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Hope this helps!

Jamie

Comment: I'm developing the web page using WordPress editor. I added your suggestion to the editors code but still is not working, am I doing it wrong?:<h1 style="font-size: 2em; margin-top: 24px; margin-bottom: 16px; line-height: 1.25; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal;"><img src="github-link-case-sensitive.png"/>http://github.com/FL-ASGS/ECFL-IRL/blob/master/plots/NAM/EW_Lansing_Island.png</a></h1>
<div></div>

Comment: Two small issues I've noticed here: you are not posting a direct link to the image, and haven't used the tag correctly. No big deal! These are easy to fix.

The link you've provided in your comment should look something like this:

<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FL-ASGS/ECFL-IRL/master/plots/NAM/EW_Lansing_Island.png">

This is the direct link to that image and notice that the "src" tag quotations encapsulate the full link before ending.

This link when pasted into the browser will show you the image and nothing more.